# Run shell .sh script in Terminal from MacOs SwiftUI App

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, swiftui, xcode12

I want to create a SwiftUI MacOs App to run shell scripts from my App.
Therefore I want to open the Terminal and paste a .sh or the content of this script and run it.
First I got an permission denied error which I solved by removing the sandbox mode.

But now all commands within the script like npm or mvn lead me to the error:
`"zsh:1: command not found: npm\n"`

Do you have a solution for my problem?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var title : String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          
            Button(action: {
                runCommand()
            }) {
                Text("Run")
            }
        }
    }
}


func runCommand() {

    let path = "/Users/User1/Desktop/test.sh"
    print( shell("/Users/User1/Desktop/test.sh start") )
}

func shell(_ command: String) -> (String?) {
    let task = Process()

    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return (output)
}
```

Comment: Where is `npm` installed? Is the `PATH` correct in your subprocess?

Comment: npm is installed in usr/local/bin.. Is it not possible to simply open a terminal window and paste my string?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Try adding `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` before launching `zsh`, or add the same setting to your Zsh startup file.

Comment: I'm not very familiar to bash /zsh ... I just want to provide the user a possibility to add "shortcuts" for shell script which he then simply can start with button press.  So the question is when I have a .sh script I simply want to press a run button and then a terminal window should appear and run *.sh start

Comment: The error seems to come from inside the shell script. The script runs fine, but it contains a call to a command which cannot be found. This indicates that the script runs with an incomplete or munged `PATH`. The obbious fix is to make sure you have a correct `PATH` before starting the shell.

Comment: Try `shell("env PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH /Users/User1/Desktop/test.sh start")` as a quick proof of concept. If that works, figure out a more robust way to ensure the program has a correct `PATH` when it starts.

Comment: @tripleee I think this worked with a complex script, but I don't see any outputs. So it would be nice to see the output which I would get wenn running in terminal, is this possible?

Comment: I don't know anything about Swift, but your code looks like it should return the output when the subprocess finishes.

Comment: Ah okay. The problem is that I am running a background process with this script and though I can't see what's happening because in only finishes when I am quitting it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to change your `/Users/User1/Desktop/test.sh` script and use the full path for `npm` (eg. /opt/homebrew/bin/npm or wherever your npm is installed) instead of relying on PATH and/or environment variables.
As an alternative set the PATH variable in you shell script pointing at the correct directory where `npm` is installed on your host. Depending on the shell your script is using this must be done differently (setenv PATH, export PATH, PATH =  ...)